# How to store random numbers in a two dimensional array in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I want to store random numbers between 1 to 25 in a two dimensional array.
I want the result like the bellow:

Means storing random numbers in a Array[5][5] by Javascript:

Answer (score 0):

You really should be showing what you tried but I guess for the sake of it...

```
var result = new Array(5);
for(i = 0; i < 5; i++){
 result[i] = new Array(5);
  for(j = 0; j < 5; j++){
    result[i][j] = Math.floor((Math.random()*25) + 1);
  }
}
```

OP question:
the result is repeats elements. But I don't want any repeats. How can it possible ?
create an array with # 1-25 shuffle it and then put it in a two dimensional array as shown above.
[How can I shuffle an array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6274339/how-can-i-shuffle-an-array-in-javascript)